# Why does my ethernet connection fail AFTER installation is complete?

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

I am installing Ubuntu for the first time on an old laptop (Inspiron 6400) and have run into an odd problem right off the bat.  During installation, I am directed to connect the computer to the internet via ethernet cable.  I do this, and have no problem establishing a connection.  I get no warnings or error messages during the install process.

Once I am finished installing and log in, I suddenly cannot access the network via ethernet.  At all.

I tried poking around in the wireless connections but I don't have enough experience to recognize what might be a problem.
I tried reinstalling the OS and that did nothing.  If anyone has any insight into this problem or even just some guidance on how to troubleshoot, then I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get to the desktop, right-click on the NetworkManager icon in the upper right and uncheck "Enable Wireless". This should let your wired ethernet act as it did before, and then you might have another questions to ask.

Comment: I did as you suggested and nothing changed as far as I can tell.  During the installation all I had to do to get the ethernet to work was plug in the cable.  Is there something else I can/should do to get the ethernet port to connect?